# How to tell when a stream with pipes finished draining

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a stream that is composed from a chain of pipes.
I am using [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream)  package to create the building blocks of the pipes.
The code gets a file from S3, unzips it, parses it and send the data to some async function
I am trying to get the promise resolved when it finished handling that file.
How can I be sure that the all the chain has finished draining?
My current solution looks like this.
it looks bad and I still think that there is a possibility that `resolve()`
will be called while there are data chunks in the gzReader for example.

thanks

```
const inputStream = this.s3client.getObject(params).createReadStream()
inputStream.on('end',() => {
console.log("Finished handling file " + fileKey)
let stopInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (counter == 0) {
        resolve(this.eventsSent)
        clearInterval(stopInterval)
      }
    }, 300)
  })
const gzReader = zlib.createGunzip();
inputStream
  .pipe(gzReader)
  .pipe(es.split())
  .pipe(es.parse())
  .pipe(es.mapSync(data => {
    counter++
    this.eventsSent.add(data.data)
    asyncFunc(this.destinationStream, data.data)
      .then(() => {
        counter--
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        counter--
        console.error('Failed sending event '  + data.data + e)
      })
  }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never initialize counter, it is zero and after the first 300ms, your function resolves (which can be before your pipes are working and increase the counter).

So don't use `setInterval` ;) You don't need it.

Also there is no need to use mapSync, if you already call an async function in it. Just use map and pass the data and callback (https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream#map-asyncfunction). Don't forget to call the callback in your async function!

Add a last step in your pipe: `wait(callback)` (https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream#wait-callback)
There you can resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) actually I initialised the counter before the beginning of the snippet so it works.  
The solution seems to be working. thanks! 
just a quick question is you don't mind. why does it matter if I call map or mapSync If I call an async function inside anyways?

Comment: @OhadBasan I would answer your question with a Clean Code principle: KISS ("keep it simple, stupid" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). So don't call `map` or `mapSync` with an arrow function, in which you call another function. Just pass the async function as parameter to `map`. Like this: `.pipe(es.map(asyncFunc)).pipe...` and `asyncFunc` has a type signature like `asyncFunc(data)`. PS: It's just sample code ;)